# how tune hosts for apache2?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, hosts

please help solve the problem.

on ubuntu i install apache2. and create 2 sites:
/var/www/html/site1.ru/index.html:

```
<div>site1</div>
```

/var/www/html/site2.ru/index.html:

```
<div>site2</div>
```

i tune config for virtualhosts: /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1.ru
  ServerNmae site1.ru
  Alias www.site1.ru
 </VirtualHost>
```

and /etc/apache2/sites-available/site2-config.conf:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2.ru
  ServerNmae site2.ru
  Alias www.site2.ru
 </VirtualHost>
```

also run:

```
 sudo a2ensite site2-config.conf
```

i need tune file /etc/hosts. Now it looks like this:

```
localhost   site1.ru
localhost   www.site1.ru
localhost   site2.ru
localhost   www.site2.ru

..........
............
```

but on browser via address localhost display only page of site1.ru . other sites is unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use IP in hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   site1.ru
127.0.0.1   www.site1.ru
127.0.0.1   site2.ru
127.0.0.1   www.site2.ru
```